# How do you design a C++ class without making a std::vector a public member?

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I've seen this question: [Class design with vector as a private/public member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197211/class-design-with-vector-as-a-private-public-member), but I don't feel that it answers the question.

I have a class called `PrimeSieve` that can be initialized as `PrimeSieve s(10000)` to perform actions such as checking whether a number under 10000 is prime or listing all the primes under 10000. In particular, I'm wondering how to perform the latter function.

Currently, I'm doing this, which I think violates the principles of OOP:

```
class PrimeSieve {
public:
...
     std::vector<long long> primes;
```

The client will never need to change the vector, but how can I still allow the client to iterate through a vector of all of the primes under some number (using things like `vector.size()`? I've thought about an accessor method that returns the vector by value, but that seems inefficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would define the class as:

```
class PrimeSieve 
{
public:

    typedef std::vector<long long>::const_iterator const_iterator;

    const_iterator begin() const  { return primes.begin(); }
    const_iterator end() const  { return primes.end(); }

    long long  operator[](int index) const { return primes[i]; }

    size_t   size() const { return primes.size(); }

    //rest of the members which compute the primes!

private:
   std::vector<long long> primes ;
} ;
```

I think the user of the class should have *read-only* access to the vector, so I used `const_iterator` in the typedef definition. Also note that the `operator[]` is a `const` member function which means you can only access the value, but cannot modify it.

Usage:

```
 PrimeSieve sieve(1000); //compute

 //print to stdout
 std::copy(sieve.begin(), 
           sieve.end(), 
           std::ostream_iterator<long long>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: This is a good approach, as it allows some implementation details to vary later with client code continuing to work unchanged (after a recompile).  Specifically, the implementation of the iterators could be changed later to e.g. generate an arbitrary number of results (CPU time allowing), rather than having a hard-coded limit, and the most crucial client usage - `begin()` and dereferencing/incrementing the iterator it returns - could continue to work.  That's one reason to consider whether you really need `end()` and `size()` in your interface: can the client decide when they've "had enough"?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm curious about weighing the two possibilities--what are the advantages of this approach over the one suggested by TonyK's below?

Comment: @Louis: As the comment before yours says this solution has the flexibility to change *internally* without requiring the client to change their code, as this doesn't expose the internal details of the implementation. For example, if you change `std::vector` to `std::list`, the client code would not need to change, as the client works with pair of iterators, and it need not worry about whether `PriveSieve` internally uses vector or list.[contd.]

Comment: [contd] However, the other solution by @TonyK depends on the internal details, so if you change `std::vector` to `std::list`, the client have to change the code as well.

Answer (score 6):

This is one way to do it:

```
class PrimeSieve {
public:
  const std::vector<long long>& getPrimes() const {
    return primes ;
    }
private:
  std::vector<long long> primes ;
} ;
```

There is no inefficiency here -- returning a reference is at least as efficient as returning a pointer. And the client can iterate through the vector returned by `getPrimes` (using a `const_iterator`, naturally).

Answer (score 1):

```
public:
    const std::vector<long long>* getPrimes() const { return &primes; }
private:
    std::vector<long long> primes;
```

This gives clients access to a `const` pointer to `primes` which means they can iterate over it but cannot modify it.

(My syntax may be wrong; it's been a few years since I've done any serious C++)

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule is:
You make the data member `private` & then provide `public`/`protected` member functions to expose the functionality/operations which is provided on the `private` data member.

You should follow the same rule here.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is do design a special iterator class:

```
class PrimeSieve {
  mutable std::vector<long long> primes;
 public:

  class const_iterator;
  friend class const_iterator;
  class const_iterator{   // should probably inherit from some std::iterator class, not sure there
    const PrimeSieve *domain;
    unsigned index;
   public:
    const_iterator(const PrimeSieve &d): domain(&d), index(0) {}
    const long long &operator *() const{return domain->primes[index];}
    const_iterator &operator++(){
      if (++index >= domain->primes.size()) {
        // calculate a number of "new" primes here
      }
      return *this;
    }
  }

  const_iterator begin() const {return const_iterator(*this);}
};
```

The good thing about this is that the container is now "infinite": primes are calculated lazily as needed, rather than up to a given upper bound.

Comment: This is a good pattern, but the sieve algorithm is designed around a fixed upper bound.

Comment: @Krumelur yes, but it's easy to expand the algorithm so that you can continue the calculation from that bound, and if you increase the bound in the same manner as `std::vector` increases its memory then the computional overhead amortizes.